# Writing generic instances for Fix/Mu in F-algebras

Tags: haskell, typeclass, algebra, recursive-datastructures, fixpoint-combinators

After reading [Milewski's F-algebra article](http://fpcomplete.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras), I tried to implement it and use for a real-world problem.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to write instances for `Fix`,

```
newtype Fix f = Fx { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unFix
```

For example, let's say I this simple algebra:

```
data NatF a = Zero | Succ a   deriving Eq
type Nat    = Fix NatF
```

and now I try to implement an instance of `Eq` (note: `deriving` doesn't work):

```
instance ??? => Eq (Fix f) where
  (==) = ???
```

And this is where I get stuck.  How do I fill in the `???` to make this work?  Is this even possible to do?

Comment: You might want to make the Eq instance for Fix NatF specifically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest instance I could find was just

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Function (on)

instance Eq (f (Fix f)) => Eq (Fix f) where
  (==) = (==) `on` unFix
```

All that we require is that `Fix f` is an instance of `Eq` precisely when `f (Fix f)` is an instance of `Eq`. Since in general we have instances like `Eq a => Eq (f a)` this works just fine.

```
 > Fx Zero == Fx Zero
   True
```